# link: keyword does not return as many Google search results as expected

Tags: google-search

It used to be that if I wanted to find what pages linked to some page then I could use the `link:` keyword filter.

But trying it now it's clearly not working or at least not for me.

- `link:http://www.yahoo.co.uk`   returned 241 results. I'd expect millions
- `link:www.yahoo.com`  returns 6000 results, I expect millions+
- `link:www.dogpile.com`  692 results. Gotta be way more.

I never ran the test years ago, but I've always assumed the `link:` keyword worked. I've used it to locate things before. Though testing now it looks like it doesn't work properly, it's not picking up anywhere near enough results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Search Operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#link)

> **link**:
>
> The query `link:URL` shows pages that point to that URL. For example, to
>   find pages that point to Google Guide’s home page, enter:
>
> `link:www.googleguide.com`
>
> Note:
>
> According to Google’s documentation, “you cannot combine a `link:`
>   search with a regular keyword search.”
>
> Also note that when you combine `link:` with another advanced operator,
>   Google may not return all the pages that match. The following queries
>   should return lots of results, as you can see if you remove the `-site:`
>   term in each of these queries.
>
> Find links to the Google home page not on Google’s own site.
>
> - `link:www.google.com -site:google.com`
>
> Find links to the UK Owners Direct home page not on its own site.
>
> - `link:www.www.ownersdirect.co.uk -site:ownersdirect.co.uk`

The above source says **The following queries should return lots of results, as you can see if you remove the `-site:` term in each of these queries.**

However when testing I found that adding the `-site:` term produced **more** results (the **opposite** of the above statement):

- `link:http://www.yahoo.co.uk` returns 241 results
- `link:http://www.yahoo.co.uk -site:yahoo.co.uk` returns about 77,000,000 results